# Selenium WebDriver: Check if element present or not for a while loop?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

Suppose there is page in which I want to check if an element "abc" is present on the page or not. If the element is not present then I want to click on some other element "xyz", and then new page opens up and again I want to check if the element "abc" is present on the page. If again not present then click on the same element "xyz" and this goes on.

I used while loop and below is the code. Please help me out.

In my below code: "elem_prev" is the element I want to check every time if it is present on the page or not. 
My code is not working, now it is not able to find the element in the loop, but it should be as it is present on every page. Please help me with the concepts as well. Is the code correct?

It says for the element present in the loop that Unable to locate Element.

```
Boolean elem_prev = driver.findElements(By.id("TM_TL_DD_WRK_GET_DATA")).size()!=0;
    while(elem_prev==false)
    {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.className("PSHYPERLINK")).click();

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        Alert a = driver.switchTo().alert();
        a.dismiss();

        Thread.sleep(10000);

        elem_prev = driver.findElements(By.id("TM_TL_DD_WRK_GET_DATA")).size()!=0;
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: code is not working means what . getting any error or what would you want?

Comment: I want to know how to actually write the code for the 1st paragraph of my question and if I have written the correct code.

Comment: Code looks fine (at a first glance). Which line is the exception complaining about? To me it looks like PSHYPERLINK could be the problem. Just a wild guess: Is PSHYPERLINK not the class name but the id of your link?

Comment: It is the class name, I tried with id name also but giving the same error NoSuchElementException. It is for the line "driver.findElement(By.className("PSHYPERLINK")).click();"

Comment: You can't just move to next page after clicking the element you have to use driver.switchTo().window() method

Comment: The same page reloads

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you find the elements out of the loop like this:

```
WebElement element1 = driver.findElements(By.id("TM_TL_DD_WRK_GET_DATA"));
WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.className("PSHYPERLINK"));

while(element1==false){
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    element2.click();

    Thread.sleep(2000);
    Alert a = driver.switchTo().alert();
    a.dismiss();

    Thread.sleep(10000);

    element1.size()!=0;
}
```

and then try a `SystemOutPrintln(element1);` and/or `SystemOutPrintln(element2);` before the loop starts to be sure it actually finds the element.

If it doesn't print an element, then the problem is not the loop, but the way you try to find the element.

This would be important information as you can then try to find the element in other way.

Comment: guys, can you please also explain the down-votes?
not having enough info gets to guessing and both printing to console and getting your elements beforehand are good practices.
If people get to understand the problem better, they can answer more precisely and explaining why a solution is not good can help understanding the problem.
Also it would be useful to have the solution as well when/if you find it.